# npm failing to rename

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js, npm-install

I'm trying to install a Sail.js app, however it constantly fails when attempting npm i.

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Node\mmol\node_modules\.staging\sails-99c85f08\node_modules\@sailshq\body-parser
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Node\mmol\node_modules\.staging\sails-99c85f08\node_modules\@sailshq\body-parser' -> 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Node\mmol\node_modules\.staging\@sailshq\body-parser-e780f048'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-02T20_15_43_291Z-debug.log
```

The dependencies are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ejs": "2.3.4",
    "grunt": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jst": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "1.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-sails-linker": "~0.10.1",
    "grunt-sync": "0.5.2",
    "include-all": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "rc": "1.0.1",
    "sails": "~0.12.14",
    "sails-disk": "~0.10.9",
    "sails-mongo": "^0.12.2"
  },
```

I'm at a complete loss.  I've cleared the npm cache, I've reinstalled Node.  Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: What command you entered?

Comment: ```npm install```

Comment: Have you tried deleting `C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Node\mmol\node_modules`?

Comment: Yep.  Deleted the node_modules folder, cleared the npm cache, still no joy

Comment: Have you tried `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm` command
and then re-install Node.js

Comment: I'm on Windows Server, not Unix

Comment: What about in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm`?  Did node/npm leave some stuff in there?  Does that exist on your system?

Comment: That exists, but its just a the npm folder inside the npm_modules folder there